# Problems with "simple-mesh" smooth shading

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, artifacts

I'm modeling a wooden elephant and using [this method for cleaning the topology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGL6QpVRyXk).

I'm having a little problem with a "simple" mesh, when adding a subdivision-surface-modifier and applying the *Shade-Smooth*.

As shown on the video, near the base of the legs and the "bridge" between the legs looks kind of pointy instead of smooth. It really confuses me given that in theory I have a simple topology.

I already recalculated the normals in various ways and the problem persists.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be something simple, I tried to recreate and this solution worked:

[image]

[select the face and click "X" or "delete" key and "dissolve vertices" (this will delete the vertices of the selected face without making a hole)]

the subdivision surface modifier use the edges distances to apply calculate smooth, if one edge is close to another, the modifier will less smooth.

Comment: tthanks for the reply (: but his doesn`t quite solve my problem, because it gets rid of necessary vertices for proper modeling :(

Comment: the subdivision surface modifier works based on your mesh topology; if you cannot change the mesh, this modifier will not work as you expect :(